# Magento 2 Paylike Payment Method

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway, checkout-page

I have installed and configured the **paylike** (payment method) in magento 2 using this link [Magento 2 Paylike](https://github.com/paylike/plugin-magento) i have configured the sandbox(Test) api keys (details).

The order details showing correctly in the admin end

**I)** After order has been completed it redirects to **checkout/cart** instead of success page.

[image]

**II)** The order details doesn't showing in the customer dashboard (orders section).

[image]

Could you please **suggest/help** me how to debug & fix the above errors?

Comment: If your redirected back to cart this means there has been an error after the payment was made usually this is when it saves the order. I'd recommend viewing log files to see if anything is in there if so if you post here we can give you a better answer

Comment: thanks for your reply @dava gordon,  let me check and get back with the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin here: https://github.com/paylike/plugin-magento-2, this is a version that has been developed specifically for magento-2 and has been tested.